# Query replace lookup string from joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, replace

I have a somewhat complex query joining many tables and I have one "column" in the result that is a concatenation of other columns. Now I need to take the results of this concatenation and lookup this value in a lookup table and return the associated correct string replacing the original string if there is a matching value.

EDIT: I created an SQL Fiddle to help. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/209437/1

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT prices.part_no AS sku, CONCAT_WS(' | ', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat.`category` SEPARATOR ' | '), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(' > ', c.`section_code`, c.`lev1_subcategory_name`, c.`lev2_subcategory_name`, c.`lev3_subcategory_name`) SEPARATOR ' | ')) AS category
FROM parts_file_prices AS prices
LEFT JOIN parts_file_content AS c on prices.`part_no` = c.`part_no` AND prices.`batch_id` = c.`batch_id`
LEFT JOIN parts_file_categories AS cat on prices.`part_no` = cat.`part_no`
WHERE prices.`batch_id` = 1 AND (c.`catalog_part_description` IS NOT NULL AND c.`catalog_part_description` != '')
GROUP BY sku
ORDER BY prices.`part_no` asc LIMIT 5;
```

Here is the result:

```
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sku     | category                                                                                                                                |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 11-2000 | Best Selling > Test | Best Selling > Test 2 | Best Selling > Test > Test Sub | 2 > Books & CD's > Technical Books | 2 > Technical Books |
| 11-3000 | 2 > Books & CD's > Technical Books | 2 > Technical Books                                                                                |
| 11-8006 | 2 > Books & CD's                                                                                                                        |
| 11-8033 | 2 > Books & CD's > Log/Record Books | 2 > Log/Record Books                                                                              |
| 11-8034 | 2 > Books & CD's > Log/Record Books | 2 > Log/Record Books                                                                              |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have never asked an SQL question so if more info is needed please say so.
I need to lookup this concatenated value "2 > Books & CD's > Technical Books" in my table parts_file_category_overrides and return the replace value from that table into my result row.

My ending result needs to look like this:

```
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sku     | category                                                                                                                                |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 11-2000 | Best Selling > Test | Best Selling > Test 2 | Best Selling > Test > Test Sub | Inside Living > Books                                    |
| 11-3000 | Inside Living > Books                                                                                                                   |
| 11-8006 | Inside Living > Books                                                                                                                   |
| 11-8033 | Inside Living > Books                                                                                                                   |
| 11-8034 | Inside Living > Books                                                                                                                   |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here are my tables with some data:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM parts_file_prices LIMIT 5;
+----+----------+---------+--------------------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
| id | batch_id | part_no | description              | dealer_price | manufacturer_no | upc          |
+----+----------+---------+--------------------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
|  1 |        1 | 11-2000 | TRAILER/FIFTH WHEEL BOOK |         4.66 | A02-2000        | 019079200020 |
|  2 |        1 | 11-3000 | MOTOR HOME BOOK          |         4.66 | A02-3000        | 019079200037 |
|  3 |        1 | 11-8006 | "MOM'S CAMPER COOKING"   |         6.65 | MOMS            | 799530378986 |
|  4 |        1 | 11-8033 | CAMPER'S DAILY LOG       |         9.54 | NULL            | 831196001522 |
|  5 |        1 | 11-8034 | DAILY LOG REFILL         |         4.86 | NULL            | 831196001546 |
+----+----------+---------+--------------------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM parts_file_content LIMIT 5;
+----+----------+---------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+--------+-------+--------+--------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+
| id | batch_id | part_no | section_code | lev1_subcategory_name | lev2_subcategory_name | lev3_subcategory_name | group_name      | mfg_part_num | catalog_part_description               | weight | text_body                                                                                                                                                                        | 250_image_location      | length | width | height | manufacturer             | logo_location                    | b2ccategory    | subcategory1 | subcategory2   |
+----+----------+---------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+--------+-------+--------+--------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+
|  1 |        1 | 11-2000 |            2 | Books & CD's          | Technical Books       | NULL                  | RVing Made Easy | A02-2000     | RVing Made Easy, Trailers/Fifth Wheels |  0.190 | Written by a long-time RVer who shares his experience, covers important operating and safety features. Hints follow each section listing do's and don'ts. 48 pages. Priced each. | 112/250/112000_silo.jpg |   0.25 |  5.50 |   8.38 | VALTERRA PRODUCTS, INC.  | Null                             | Inside Your RV | BOOKS        | RV MAINTENANCE |
|  2 |        1 | 11-2000 |            2 | Books & CD's          | Technical Books       | NULL                  | RVing Made Easy | A02-2000     | RVing Made Easy, Trailers/Fifth Wheels |  0.190 | Written by a long-time RVer who shares his experience, covers important operating and safety features. Hints follow each section listing do's and don'ts. 48 pages. Priced each. | 112/250/112000_silo.jpg |   0.25 |  5.50 |   8.38 | VALTERRA PRODUCTS, INC.  | 009050/weblogo/valterra_silo.jpg | Inside Your RV | BOOKS        | RV MAINTENANCE |
|  3 |        1 | 11-2000 |            2 | Technical Books       | NULL                  | NULL                  | RVing Made Easy | A02-2000     | RVing Made Easy, Trailers/Fifth Wheels |  0.190 | Written by a long-time RVer who shares his experience, covers important operating and safety features. Hints follow each section listing do's and don'ts. 48 pages. Priced each. | 112/250/112000_silo.jpg |   0.25 |  5.50 |   8.38 | VALTERRA PRODUCTS, INC.  | Null                             | Inside Your RV | BOOKS        | RV MAINTENANCE |
|  4 |        1 | 11-2000 |            2 | Technical Books       | NULL                  | NULL                  | RVing Made Easy | A02-2000     | RVing Made Easy, Trailers/Fifth Wheels |  0.190 | Written by a long-time RVer who shares his experience, covers important operating and safety features. Hints follow each section listing do's and don'ts. 48 pages. Priced each. | 112/250/112000_silo.jpg |   0.25 |  5.50 |   8.38 | VALTERRA PRODUCTS, INC.  | 009050/weblogo/valterra_silo.jpg | Inside Your RV | BOOKS        | RV MAINTENANCE |
|  5 |        1 | 11-3000 |            2 | Books & CD's          | Technical Books       | NULL                  | RVing Made Easy | A02-3000     | RVing Made Easy, Motorhomes            |  1.000 | Written by a long-time RVer who shares his experience, covers important operating and safety features. Hints follow each section listing do's and don'ts. 48 pages. Priced each. | 113/250/113000_silo.jpg |   0.13 |  5.50 |   8.50 | VALTERRA PRODUCTS, INC.  | Null                             | Inside Your RV | BOOKS        | RV MAINTENANCE |
+----+----------+---------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+--------+-------+--------+--------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM parts_file_categories LIMIT 5;
+----+---------+--------------------------------+
| id | part_no | category                       |
+----+---------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | 11-2000 | Best Selling > Test            |
|  2 | 11-2000 | Best Selling > Test 2          |
|  3 | 11-2000 | Best Selling > Test            |
|  4 | 11-2000 | Best Selling > Test > Test Sub |
+----+---------+--------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM parts_file_category_overrides LIMIT 5;
+----+-------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| id | search                              | replace               |
+----+-------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | 2 > Books & CD's > Technical Books  | Inside Living > Books |
|  2 | 2 > Technical Books                 | Inside Living > Books |
|  3 | 2 > Books & CD's > Log/Record Books | Inside Living > Books |
|  4 | 2 > Log/Record Books                | Inside Living > Books |
|  5 | 2 > Books & CD's                    | Inside Living > Books |
+----+-------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use subquery and try something like this:

```
select sku, case when o.replace is not null then o.replace else category end as category                    
FROM (
SELECT prices.part_no AS sku, CONCAT_WS(' | ', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat.`category` SEPARATOR ' | '), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(' > ', c.`section_code`, c.`lev1_subcategory_name`, c.`lev2_subcategory_name`, c.`lev3_subcategory_name`) SEPARATOR ' | ')) AS category
FROM parts_file_prices AS prices
LEFT JOIN parts_file_content AS c on prices.`part_no` = c.`part_no` AND prices.`batch_id` = c.`batch_id`
LEFT JOIN parts_file_categories AS cat on prices.`part_no` = cat.`part_no`
WHERE prices.`batch_id` = 1 AND (c.`catalog_part_description` IS NOT NULL AND c.`catalog_part_description` != '')
GROUP BY sku
ORDER BY prices.`part_no` asc) 
as test LEFT JOIN parts_file_category_overrides AS o on o.`search` = category COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|SKU        | CATEGORY
|11-2000    | Best Selling > Test | Best Selling > Test 2 | Best Selling > Test > Test Sub | 2 > Books & CD's > Technical Books | 2 > Technical Books
|11-3000    | Inside Living > Books 
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You might have it a lot easier if your foreign key in **parts_file_category_overrides** not a concatinated from a lot of column.

Comment: It seems to be working on the second row, but the first row still has "2 > Books & CD's > Technical Books | 2 > Technical Books" which also needs replaced.

Comment: But your question is you want is "I need to lookup this concatenated value "2 > Books & CD's > Technical Books" in my table parts_file_category_overrides and return the replace value from that table into my result row." AND also your first row is best selling not the part in parts_file_category_overrides